# Using numpy where with applymap in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use numpy `where` in conjunction with `applymap` in pandas.

Sample DF:

```
f = [[1,5],[20,40],[100,21],[15,19],[-46,101]]
test = pd.DataFrame(f,columns=["A","B"])
test
```

OP:

```
    A   B
0   1   5
1   20  40
2   100 21
3   15  19
4   -46 101
```

Condition is, if a column value is greater than 50 or less than 25 it should be changed to 0 or it should remain as it is.

Code:

```
test = test.applymap(lambda x:np.where((test[x]>50)| (test[x]<25), 0,test[x]) )
test
```

Error:

```
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: (1, 'occurred at index A')
```

Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
test.mask(test.lt(25)|test.gt(50),0)
```

or  [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
test.where(test.ge(25) & test.le(50),0)
```

**Output**

```
   A   B
0  0   0
1  0  40
2  0   0
3  0   0
4  0   0
```

Using [`DataFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) we could do:

```
test.applymap(lambda x: 0 if (x>50) or (x<25) else x)
```

but this could become slow for large data frames

---

Solution with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.where((test<25)|(test>50),0,test),index = test.index,columns = test.columns)
```

**EDIT**

```
mean_test = test.mean()
limit = 5
df_filtered = test.mask(test.gt(mean_test.add(limit))|
                        test.lt(mean_test.sub(limit)),0)
print(df_filtered)
    A   B
0   0   0
1  20  40
2   0   0
3  15   0
4   0   0
```

Comment: this is great! I have 1 more doubt, what if I want to calculate the greater than number (50 in this case) and the lesser than number (25 in this case) for each column say through mean, which could be the better option?

Comment: What would be the expected output in that case?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the average of those over 50 and those under 25 for each column?

Comment: The condition is still the same. But instead of hardcoding the upper limit as 50 and lower limit as 25 for each column, I want to set the upper limit as ```mean(column) + 5``` and lower limit as ```mean(column) - 5```

Comment: you may find it useful to know that you can calculate the variance and the standard deviation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html , https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html ,for example: `mean_test.add(test.std().mul(3**1/2))`

Comment: https://necromuralist.github.io/kaggle-competitions/posts/mean-encoding-the-competition-data/#orga0f0979

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20,size=(10, 2)), columns=list('BC'))
sample_df["date"]= ["2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01","2020-02-01",
                    "2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02"]
sample_df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df["date"])
sample_df.set_index(sample_df["date"],inplace=True)
sample_df["A"]=[10,10,10,10,10,12,1,3,4,2]
del sample_df["date"]
sample_df


def func(df,n_bins):
    try:
        proc_col = pd.qcut(df["A"].values, n_bins, labels=range(0,n_bins))
        return proc_col
    except:
        proc_col = pd.qcut(df.mean(axis =1).values, n_bins, labels=range(0,n_bins))
        return proc_col

sample_df["A"]=sample_df.groupby([sample_df.index.get_level_values(0)])[["C","A"]].apply(lambda df: func(df,3))
sample_df


B   C   A
date            
2020-02-01  1   16  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-01  5   19  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-01  2   16  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-01  12  11  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-01  15  10  [1, 2, 1, 0, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-02  19  17  [2, 0, 1, 2, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-02  17  7   [2, 0, 1, 2, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-02  14  1   [2, 0, 1, 2, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-02  19  13  [2, 0, 1, 2, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 ...
2020-02-02  15  13  [2, 0, 1, 2, 0] Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 .
```